# Maximum height of element by class isn't updating on screen resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this script to get the maximum height of the target element (a "p" element within an element with class "col4home2"):

```
var maxHeight=0;
$('.col4home2 p').each(function(){
    maxHeight=Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
}).height(maxHeight);
```

It works on page load. However, I call this script again when the window is resized. When that happens, I get the same value for the maximum height, even though the resize causes the text to reflow, and the height of the "p" element is clearly larger.

Is this a browser issue? Or something in my code is not refreshing the value of maxHeight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery code sets an explicit pixel height on all paragraphs on page load. When you resize the page, the paragraphs maintain the specified height (their content might overflow of course).

Solution: On page resize you must first *undo* the explicit height so that the paragraphs size to match their content:

```
$('.col4home2 p').height('auto');
```

Then recalculate the heights:

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$('.col4home2 p').height('auto').each(function() {
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
}).height(maxHeight);
```